# Exclude a subdirectory from git repository

Tags: git, qt-creator

First of all I know .gitignore.
The problem is my home directory on my OS X is a git repository because when I setup a new remote linux machine for example, I wanna copy my .vimrc, .vim, .config, etc easily so I made my home directory a git repository. The problem is I have this subdirectory "Projects" in my home directory, whenever I try to add a new Project in Qt Creator (and it creates projects in my "~/Projects" directory) it asks me if I want to create a git repository for it - and I DO want to create a git repository for it - it adds the new project to ~/.git repository instead of running git init for it. I guess it happens because it understands that there's already a git repository for ~/Projects/ I mean if you run `git status` in ~/Projects/ it shows ~/.git's status, I've added Projects to ~/.gitignore but it didn't help, I wanna exclude Projects from ~/.git in a way that when I run `git status` in ~/Projects, it shows me this error:

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

which is the error returned by git when there's no git repository there at all. Is it possible? Or maybe there may be an option in Qt-Creator that solves my problem?

Comment: You could use a dotfile manager, which puts your files in another folder ~/dotfiles for example and symlinks them for you . https://github.com/justone/dfm

Comment: I don't need a software for that, I can run mv, and then ln -l in command line myself. btw dfm doesn't make symlinks, it manages dotfiles, and I prefer a git solution instead of choosing another approach for managing dotfiles or making symlinks, if there's no git solution and there's no qt-creator solution, I'd go with symlink solution.

Comment: dfm uses git, it just gives you some commands to automatically symlink the files in the repository

Answer (score 0):

You can put the repository and worktree wherever you like, there doesn't have to be a `.git` at the worktree root if you explicitly set `GIT_WORK_TREE` and `GIT_DIR`:

```
( export  GIT_WORK_TREE=$HOME
  export  GIT_DIR=$HOME/.local/etc/dotfiles.git
  git checkout
)
```